# mvc 5 @html.editorfor class do not fit parent width

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, styles

I am doing an MVC 5 Application. On My View I have an `@html.editorfor` inside a `<div>` that do not fit the way I want.

this is my View Code.

```
  <div class="DvCampoAct" style="border:1px solid black">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.user.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new {@class = "StyleOb", @onclick = "ocultar();", placeholder = "Insert you Email." } })
                </div>
```

the class of my div `DvCampoAct` is like this. I added an black border to show the width of the div.

```
.DvCampoAct{
    float:left;
    width:75%;
    padding-bottom:5px;
}
```

the Style of then `EditFor` (StyleOB) is like this.

```
.StyleOb
 {
    height:30px;
    width:100%;
    padding:2px 0 0 2px;
    border:1px solid #BEBEBE;
    background-color:#F0F8FF;
}
```

the way it looks is like this.

[image]

It shows Parent Div is in black... and that EditFor's width do not fit div parent width. It appears to be a 80%.

My question is why my `EditFor` does not fit 100% of parent `div`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform a search on your solution for max-width:, I had a CSS file in my Content folder that had a max-width for inputs, selects, and textareas of 280 pixels.

Maybe you can find it too:

Project/Content/Site.css

```
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}
```